# React: Firebase Config File Doesn't Work With Environment Variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

```
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = getAuth();
const db = getFirestore();

// rest of my code, being primarily functions such as `signInWithGoogle` is written here below but are irrelevant to this question
```

When I originally had all of the variables under `firebaseConfig` in their string forms, this worked. However, when I switched them out for these environment variables it no longer did and showed the following error:

[image]

The thing is, that I've used this same .env file for my MongoDB config file as such:

`const uri = process.env.DB_URI;`

This is what my `.env` file looks like:

```
DB_URI="[censored]"
API_KEY="[censored]"
AUTH_DOMAIN="[censored]"
PROJECT_ID="[censored]"
STORAGE_BUCKET="[censored]"
MESSAGE_SENDER_ID="[censored]"
APP_ID="[censored]"
MEASUREMENT_ID="[censored]"
```

My application with Firebase authentication was working until I wanted to make it so none of my files had to be gitignored by replacing strings in the firebase config file I have with these environment variables

Comment: Facing the same issue, have you found a solution for this

Comment: For me the issue is that if I just change the api key to hard coded value then it is working fine, but as soon as I load it from the environment then it doesn't work

Comment: @Saad I actually didn't end up finding a solution to this issue and left it be. I suppose you can avoid pushing the exposed keys then getting any project collaborators of yours to copy-paste the fields themselves.

Comment: So after some digging I found out that client side keys you need to prefix it with NEXT_PUBLIC, more info [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser)